# QT Binary IO, read by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, qt, binary

Is it possible to take the file that is created from this function and be read or decrypted by, let's say, javascript and have the word 'test' be pulled from the file and echoed into the browser?

The following saves a file as a Binary, non-printable characters.

```
void Save(){


    QString text = "<?xml version='1.0'?><root><child>test</child></root>";

    QFile file("/home/user/Documents/teststuff/save.txt");
    if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
        qDebug() << "Unable to write to file!";
        return;
    }

    QDataStream out(&file);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);

    out << text;

    file.flush();
    file.close();

}
```

Edit: More info:

I want it read in html/javascript. Let me start by telling you want i'm trying to accomplish.I have a program that saves and read info in binary. I don't want that data to be editable so its saves as (non-printable)binary file, but i want that text, the XML to be outputted into a webpage so it can be viewable/printed by the user.

Comment: What is your concern?

Comment: I want to read the binary file in javascript and be able to output it to the browser.

Comment: So, you are trying to ask how to read an xml file, or how you display the read in file in the browser? What have you tried yourself

Comment: The xml file is encrypted by QT, when read by a text editor it will show up as non-printable characters. I want to know if its possible to decrypt and be read by and client side html resourse, such as javascript

Answer (score 0):

> Ok, so.. my question is: Is it possible to take the file that is created from this function and be read or decrypted by, let's say, javascript and have the word 'test' be pulled from the file and echoed into the browser?

Yes, it is possible to read binary data in (see the code below proving that), parse with the Qt xml reader, and then display that in the browser.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>

void save()
{
    QString text = "<?xml version='1.0'?><root><child>test</child></root>";

    QFile file("save.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        qDebug() << file.errorString();
        return;
    }

    QDataStream out(&file);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);

    out << text;

    file.flush();
    file.close();

}

void load()
{
    QFile file("save.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qDebug() << file.errorString();
        return;
    }

    QDataStream in(&file);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_8);

    QString text;
    in >> text;

    qDebug() << "The whole text:" << text;

    QXmlStreamReader xml(text);

     while (!xml.atEnd()) {
         xml.readNext();
         if (xml.name() == QStringLiteral("child") && xml.tokenString() == QStringLiteral("StartElement")) {
             xml.readNext();
             qDebug() << "Child text found:" << xml.text();
         }
     }

    file.close();
}

int main()
{
    save();
    load();
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

> g++ -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -lQt5Core main.cpp && ./a.out

```
"<?xml version='1.0'?><root><child>test</child></root>"
Child text found: "test"
```

Your additional question about outputting an xml on the web does not make much sense. You should output an html eventually. In any case, your question is too broad with several different subquestions, and you do not seem to have put any effort into solving it yourself, unfortunately.

Comment: Problem is, i'm not trying to read it back in QT. I want it read in html/javascript. Let me start by telling you want i'm trying to accomplish.I have a program that saves and read info in binary. I don't want that data to be editable so its saves as (non-printable)binary file, but i want that text, the XML to be outputted into a webpage so it can be viewable/printed by the user.

Comment: "I want to know if its possible to decrypt" -> I answered that. The rest is irrelevant to Qt. In fact you display html in the web world usually, so I really do not understand why you would use this XML. Your second embedded question does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Be decrypted by javascript, not by qt. Let say the string wasnt xml.to begin with.. lets say it was just the word test in a binary file created by qt. Can javascript read a binary file created by qt?

Comment: There is really nothing magical about Qt here. Qt just uses the C functions underneath on Posix with the binary write argument. Javascript should be to read just fine, if you can read any binary file written by any binary low-level writer.